# I need to make this layout but I am confused as to what should I use how to place them like in the image I have posted below

Tags: flutter

Since i want this to be my layout i was trying to implement it with a showModalBottomSheet but the problem is that this widget only works on the button click as it is showing me error when i am trying to call the method as it is in the initState method. So then I started to work with bottomSheet value present in the scaffold but then the background is being displayed only upto the starting of the bottom sheet creating the distance between the model sheet and the background whereas I want it to overlap like in the image..How should I prepare this layout.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*There is no such parameter as `"bottomSheet"` in `Scaffold`, there is one called `bottomAppBar`, which is used for making Bottom Bars like the one on the Youtube Android App. So this should help you make the basic structure.*

Use a `Stack` widget to put widgets on top of each other, in first layer, add the image using the `NetworkImage` widget, then in the second layer, make a `Column`, like this:

```
@override 
Widget build() => Scaffold(
    body: _body(),
);

_body() => Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
        NetworkImage(your_url_here), 
        Column(
           children: <Widget>[
               _basicDetails(),
               _guidePanel(),
             ]
        ),
]);
```

Then create 2 new methods after the `_body` method like this:

```
_body() => Stack(...);

_basicDetailsPage() => Container();

_guidePanel() => Container();
```

Create your layout in these 2 methods. Comment if you need more help *:)*

For additional help, please join the Facebook Group *"Let's Flutter With Dart"*

Comment: Man I actually want to slide the "guide panel" over the background image when the user swipes it up or scrolls it up, how to achieve that

Comment: Didn't ever try it, but I think `Draggable` might do it

Comment: Nevermind i found out what to do,, the solution is SliverLists

Comment: @SabihKhan Great to know that, please post it as an answer for the StackOverflow community!